# sparql get all subjects that are not from a specific prefix

Tags: sparql

I have a data-set with resources using many prefixes.  I want to find all resources that are not from two specific prefixes.

I executed this query:

```
select *
where
{

 ?s ?p ?o .
  bind (strafter(str(?s), "#") as ?prefix)
  filter (?prefix != "http://www.first.com/to#")
  filter (?prefix != "http://www.second.com/rs#")
}
limit 10
```

That didn't work because

`strafter(str("http://www.first.com/to#test")` gives me `test` not `http://www.first.com/to#`.

Does anyone know how to get just the prefix please ?

Comment: For this approach, you'd want [strbefore](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strbefore), not [strafter](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strafter).  There are examples in the documentation that show what these do:  `strbefore("abc","b") => "a"` and `strafter("abc","b") => "c"`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor hello, thanks for the comment, i asked a question on meta that you could/may know it :) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323271/how-to-give-minimum-example-when-my-problem-is-in-the-size-of-the-data could you help please ?

Comment: is this the setup where you get a null punter exception on your large data set?  I would not be surprised if some uri has the form ` http://example.org/foo/bar`, that is, with no `#` in it,  so that maybe you get an empty string of null where you might not be expecting it.  (That's just a general guess though,  not necessarily what's happening here. )

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor oh no, now i have two null pointer exceptions and none of them is related to this question, i just asked this question for a task to delete some triples and it is done. but the two null pointer exceptiosn are: one that i asked explicity, and one that i asked on meta because i didn't know how to ask it

Answer (score 1):

`STRBEFORE` should work.  I.e.:

```
select *
where
{  ?s ?p ?o .
   BIND(STRBEFORE(str(?s), "#") as ?prefix)
   FILTER (?prefix != "http://www.first.com/to")
   FILTER (?prefix != "http://www.first.com/rs")
}
```

Or you could use `STRSTARTS`:

```
select *
where
{  ?s ?p ?o .
   FILTER (!(STRSTARTS(str(?s), "http://www.first.com/to#")))
   FILTER (!(STRSTARTS(str(?s), "http://www.first.com/rs#")))
}
```

`regex` could also be used:

```
select *
where
{  ?s ?p ?o .
   FILTER (!(regex(str(?s), "http://www.first.com/to|http://http://www.first.com/rs[#/]")))
}
```

...which would allow the URIs to end in a slash or hash, if that is a concern.

Comment: This is one option, but it won't scale if other conventions are used for prefixes (e.g., slashes).  You can also use **strstarts** to check whether a string begins with a particular prefix.

Comment: The OP was specifically dependent on using `#`.  I normally use strstarts, so will add that as well.

Comment: @scotthenninger in the `STRSTARTS` option, should it be a negated FILTER expression as it is in the other two options?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have corrected that.